# Cannot shut down / restart Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown, cpu, lockup, watchdog

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 dual boot option.
Everything works fine with Windows, but when I try to shut down or reboot the Ubuntu (Suspend works), then it never shuts down properly and I need to power it off using the power button. I need to find a workaround for this.

The following error appears:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p0: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p0: clean, 279395/1222992 files, 2341455/4082432 blocks
[33612.774710] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:2764]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Feel free to ask additional information.

Comment: Is the GPU in the laptop a Nvidia GPU?

Comment: Yes, it is the GeForce GTX 1050.

Comment: Do you have Intel processors? Is `intel-microcode` installed? Is your BIOS up to date? Do you know how to `fsck` your file system? Is your SSD firmware up to date? Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: `@heynnema` This is the CPU: `Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8`. How to find out if I have intel-microcode and whether my BIOS is up-to-date? I thought that Ubuntu doesn't require any additional drivers. By the way, a funny thing is that in the System Details it says that my Graphics is: `Intel® Kabylake GT2`. I think I could manage to do a fsck, should I do it? How to check if my SSD firmware is up-to-date? Thanks!
E: Here's the screenshot of additional drivers: https://snag.gy/E5glFA.jpg

Comment: It looks like you do have `intel-microcode` installed and enabled. To check your BIOS, enter the BIOS at power on time, note the version number, then go to the manufacturer's web site to determine if there's a newer version. For the SSD firmware, also go to the manufacturer's web site, and they usually have a utility to check the SSD for firmware updates. Yes, do a fsck to eliminate file system errors.

Comment: What seemed to fix the problem for me was that I switched to the Nvidia GPU driver from the additional drivers menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same issue and following Eerik Muuli's advice, everything is working just fine now.

> What seemed to fix the problem for me was that I switched to the Nvidia GPU driver from the additional drivers menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gedit /etc/init.d/alsa-utils
```

The file opens in Gedit and around the line 353 you'll find the instruction "stop)". Below this instruction you should add these two instructions:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig eth0 down
```

So, the file should be this way:

```
stop)
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig eth0 down
EXITSTATUS=0
```

After doing this, save the file, close it and restart or shutdown Ubuntu and verify if the problem continues."

///or

```
sudo /etc/default/grub 
find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"=>
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

Comment: Running GUI applications with `sudo` is a bad idea: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the terminal and running

`sudo shutdown -h`

`sudo reboot -h`

This will shut it down or

Comment: Commands in Ubuntu (or Linux or Unix in general) are case-sensitive. `Sudo` won't work, it should be `sudo`.